# Generate API key on self-hosted instance

Tags: graphhopper

I would like to know if it is possible to generate Web API keys to make requests on my GraphHopper instance? Is there an existing protocol for generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create a key for your self-hosted GraphHopper. If there was you could easily disable the check by editing the source :)

Comment: But what if I want to control accesses on the API I host? Typically, I want to permit an android app to make requests, but not another app that I didn't developped.

Comment: Protect it with a standard mechanisms like basic auth etc. Or just grab a key from our Directions API or buying a self-hosted Directions API is also possible ;)

Comment: Could you explain "Protect it with a standard mechanisms like basic auth"?

Comment: Please use our forum for discussion https://discuss.graphhopper.com/ or search 'java basic auth' ...